# Gravitational potential and its relationship to field strength

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

[image]

can someone please explain to me why potential gradient at the planets surface is not greater in magnitude than the potential gradient at surface of moon B even though planet has a much greater field strength?

I understand that the graph is the resultant G.P and so the gradient is the resultant field strength of both but nevertheless shouldn't the resultant field strength at $x=2R$ be greater than the resultant field strength at $x=D-R$

Comment: One thing that might be breaking your intuition: The planet has $8\times$ the volume of the moon, but only $3\times$ the mass. If the planet had $8\times$ the mass of the moon, which is what you might expect, the gravity would indeed be stronger at the planet's surface.

Comment: This problem is asking you to compare a planet made of rock to a moon made of lead, or something. Even though the moon is smaller, it is so much denser that the field strength at the surface is higher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a spherical body has its mass distributed spherically symmetrically, its gravitational field outside the body is the same as if all its mass were concentrated at its centre. So even though the planet has 3 times the mass of its moon, its field strength at its surface is only 3/4 that at the surface of its moon due to the moon, on account of the inverse square law – the planet has twice the radius of its moon. As you say, in each case the other body is too far away to make much difference to the surface field strength.

Comment: why do you say that the field strength is 3/4 of the moon?

Comment: For the planet, the field strength due to itself at its surface is $$g_P=\frac {3MG}{(2R)^2}=\frac 34 \frac {MG}{R^2}.$$ For its moon the field strength due to itself at its surface is $$g_M=\frac {MG}{R^2}.$$ See my answer for justification.

Comment: so that means the planet actually has a weaker gravitational field?

Comment: one last question : the field strength of the moon is larger... then why does the graph maximum ( where field strength is zero ) lie towards the right closer to the moon ? doesnt that indicate that the field of the planet is greater? or am i missing something

Comment: "so that means the planet actually has a weaker gravitational field?" Not really: the planet's field at a given distance from the centre of the planet is 3 times greater than the moon's field at the same distance from the centre of the moon! What's confusing you is that you are comparing surface values of gravitational field strength and the surface of the planet is twice as far from the centre of the planet as the moon's surface is from the centre of the moon. I hope that this comment will also take care of your second question.

Comment: ohhh i understand now its because im comparing surface values where surface values for the 2 bodies are different so its like me comparing 2 different values of R. so technically yes the planet has stronger field but i cant really compare surface values because its R and 2R. that also clears up the gradients at the surface problem thank you!

Answer (score 5):

$\left |\dfrac{d\phi_{\rm planet}}{dx} \right |=\left |g_{\rm planet}\right |=\dfrac {G\,3M}{(2R)^2}< \dfrac {G\,M}{R^2}= \left |g_{\rm moon}\right |=\left |\dfrac{d\phi_{\rm moon}}{dx} \right |$

---

If both gravitational fields are added together and noting the direction of increasing $x$ in the diagram then the gravitational field at the surface of the planet is $-\dfrac {G\,3M}{4R^2}+\dfrac {GM}{(D-2R)^2}$ and at the surface of the moon it is $+\dfrac {GM}{R^2}-\dfrac {G\,3M}{(D-R)^2}$

To illustrate what happens as the separation of the planet and moon, D, changes lets $M=1,\,R=1$ and $G=1$.

Comparing the two gravitational field is equivalent to comparing the two functions, $p(D) = -\dfrac 3 4 +\dfrac{1}{(D-2)^2}$ and $m(D) =1-\dfrac {3}{(D-1)^2}$.

Here is the [output from Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jt1set4krx) noting the graphs are only valid for $D\ge 3$.

[image]

The influence on the planet/moon on the gravitational field of the moon/planet is very small when $D>20(R)$.

---

By counting squares I have estimated that in the combined potential graph $D=23 \,R$ which then produces a gradient of the combined potential graph at $x=2(R)$ (surface of planet) is $+0.748$ and at $x=22(R)$ (surface of moon) it is $-0.994$.
Thus, the "uphill" part of the combined potential graph near the planet is less steep then the "downhill" part of the combined potential graph near the moon.

Comment: ok wait I understand that but my question is that isn't the gravitational field of the planet stronger? and isn't the negative potential of a GP graph equal to the field strength? so then why does the gradients of the graph not agree with that? the gradient at the surface of the planet is smaller in magnitude than the gradient at the moon? i hope you can clear this up for me.

Comment: *my question is that isn't the gravitational field of the planet stronger?* - No. When the planet and moon "touch" ($D=3$) the gravitation field is **towards** the centre of the moon and **away** from the centre of the planet..

Comment: @Safayousif I have added a paragraph to my answer.

Comment: i understand now thank you. i had this wrong understanding that the field of the planet is stronger at its surface, because the maximum point of the graph is further right ... i understand now thats not the case. the gradients make sense if we say moon is stronger field at the surface